# Printing a WPF UserControl created in Code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, user-controls

I have a UserControl that I instantiate in code behind and would like to print.  When I print this UserControl the code prints a blank piece of paper.  Why is this?  My code is as follows

```
private void PrintCurrentTab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
    var child = MyMainWindowViewModel.SelectedTab.Content;
    if (child is ScrollViewer)
    {
        child = (((ScrollViewer)child).Content);
    }

    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var printControl = new PrintingTemplate();
        printDlg.PrintVisual(printControl, "User Control Printing.");
    }
}
```

My UserControl is as follows

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.PrintingTemplate"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinHeight="500"
         MaxHeight="1000"
         MinWidth="200"
         MaxWidth="1000"
         Height="1056"
         Width="816">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="..\Resources\Images\PrintLogo.jpg" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" Margin="10,40,150,0" Height="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="PrintingGrid"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Label Content="Printed By:"/>
            <Label Name="PrintedBy"/>
            <Label Content="Printed On:"/>
            <Label Name="PrintedDate"/>
        </StackPanel>            
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem where I was able to print from some computers but not from one (only blank page), on a physical printer (working OK with XPS). I finally got a working solution here:

» https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9eb79e11-ee5a-4687-ad4c-a6d96276a8f4/printing-a-wpf-usercontrol?forum=wpf

```
    UserControlToPrint.Measure(New Size(816, 1056))
    UserControlToPrint.Arrange(New Rect(New Size(816, 1056)))
    UserControlToPrint.UpdateLayout()
```

Regards,

François from Québec

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the ***new*** in the following code is the culprit

```
 if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var printControl = new PrintingTemplate();
        printDlg.PrintVisual(printControl, "User Control Printing.");
    }
```

try to get the handle to the current control rather than create a **new**

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged this at all?  Your question seems incomplete, and I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish.  I DO notice that an important step is missing.  Here are some questions I have though:

1. Is `MyMainWindowViewModel.SelectedTab.Content == null`?
2. What is `child`'s type?
3. What is the purpose of `child = (((ScrollViewer)child).Content);`--that's ugly
4. Actually why is any of the `child` code in there, its not being used!

Anyways, you can't print a control that hasn't gone through a layout pass.  So now you might ask, "how do I force a control to be rendered?" Simple, like this:

```
if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var printableArea = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight)

    var printControl = new PrintingTemplate();

    //Set the drawing dimensions/boundaries - notice (Acutal)Width/Height = 0
    printControl.Measure(printableArea);
    printControl.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), printableArea);

    //"Render"!
    printcontrol.UpdateLayout();
    //At this point you should see the (Acutal)Width/Height be > 0!      

    printDlg.PrintVisual(printControl, "User Control Printing.");
}
```

Comment: Why the snark?  The question was good enough to start a discussion.  The code you provided still prints a blank page.  The only solution that I have found, and it is a hack, is to make the usercontrol a window, show the window in a minimized state, print it out and then close it.